# I need help to understand this function

Tags: javascript, arrays

This code from (**Eloquent Javascript** chapter 7 *3rd edition*).

A mail-delivery robot picking up and dropping off parcels.
The village consists of 11 places with 14 roads between them. It can be described with this array of roads.
What does the `for` loop do?

```
const roads = [
  "Alice's House-Bob's House",
  "Alice's House-Cabin",
  "Alice's House-Post Office",
  "Bob's House-Town Hall",
  "Daria's House-Ernie's House",
  "Daria's House-Town Hall",
  "Ernie's House-Grete's House",
  "Grete's House-Farm",
  "Grete's House-Shop",
  "Marketplace-Farm",
  "Marketplace-Post Office",
  "Marketplace-Shop",
  "Marketplace-Town Hall",
  "Shop-Town Hall",
];

// Okay I was trying to understand this function below but I couldn't, specially the for loop

function buildGraph(edges) {
  let graph = Object.create(null);
  function addEdge(from, to) {
    if (graph[from] == null) graph[from] == [to];
    else graph[from].push(to);
  }
  for (let [from, to] of edges.map((r) => r.split("-"))) {
    addEdge(from, to);
    addEdge(to, from);
  }
  return graph;
}
const roadGraph = buildGraph(roads);
```

Comment: What do you find hard to understand about it?

Comment: Also, you made a typo when you were writing this.

Comment: What does the for loop do?

Comment: What part of the for loop don't you understand? Do you know what the `.map()` method does? Do you know what `.split()` does? Do you know about destructuring?

Comment: You can also read about the [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`edges.map()` calls a function on each element of the `edges` array (which corresponds to the global `roads` array because it's the argument to the function). It collects all the return values into an array and returns this.

The function it calls uses `.split('-')` to split each string into an array, using `-` as the delimiter. For example, the string `"Alice's House-Bob's House"` becomes `["Alice's House", "Bob's House"]`. So together with `.map()`, this returns an array of nested arrays:

```
[
    ["Alice's House", "Bob's House"],
    ["Alice's House", "Cabin"],
    ...
]
```

The `for-of` loop then iterates over the elements of this array. Using the destructuring pattern `[from, to]` as the iteration variable assigns the variables `from` and `to` from the corresponding elements of each nested array. So on the first iteration `from = "Alice's House"` and `to = "Bob's House"`. On the second iteration `from = "Alice's House"` and `to = "Cabin"`.

The loop body then calls `addEdge()` with these variables to create graph edges that connect the two nodes in each direction.

Comment: I did not know that for loop turns the main array into nested arrays , but now every thing is okay .

Comment: `map` and `split` are creating the nested arrays. The `for` loop just iterates over them.

Comment: yeah I know map and split well , at all thank you so much